# SSH slower in 19.04?

Tags: apt, ssh, 19.04, snap, 19.10

I changed from 19.04 to 19.10 and now when I connect to my local LAN server using SSH, the initial connect takes much much longer. Before it was maybe 1/4 of a second. Now it sometimes takes 4 to 5 seconds.

This is not the only thing. I use Keypassx as a password manager. Normally the moment I click on the opening icon, the app starts almost instantaneously. Now again I wait about 4 to 5 seconds. Only difference is that I used `snap` to install Keepassx. Before I always used `apt`.

I already checked the system logs, but couldn't find any error worth mentioning.

Is this a known problem for applications starting slower in 19.10? Is there a fix for it? Is there a new overhead when starting applications?

**EDIT 1:**

I reinstalled 19.04 and SSH ist as fast as to before. Changed to 19.10 and it is slow again. DNS therefore does not seem to be the problem. Both, an Apple and a Windows system are as fast as 19.04.

My guess is `snap`. Is that worth of a thought? Do applications loaded through `snap` have a greater overhead? Hence, @user535733 might be right about the title.

**EDIT 2:**

I assume that @FedonKadifeli meant the SSH version. Here is the one I use on 19.10:

```
myuser@mysystem:~$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can it be a DNS problem? What happens when you use IP address instead of hostname? Did you try the `-v` option in `ssh`?

Comment: @user535733 Updated post with new test.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Updated post with SSH version.

Comment: `ssh -v user@lan_host` will display verbosely the steps `ssh` is taking to connect to your `lan_host`. This way, you will find out where exactly `ssh` waits...

Comment: `-v` is for **verbose** not for Version.  The version of SSH client doesn't matter as much as the verbose debug output.  Use `ssh -v user@remotesystem` where `remotesystem` is the hostname or IP address of your other machine you're trying to connect to, and track through the debug/verbose output.  It'll give you an idea of what's going on behind the scenes